# Send HTML form data in Protocol Buffer message over HTTP

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is it possible to send HTML form data in Protocol Buffer message on HTTP POST method? On server, I would parse the message and take appropriate action. An example would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean server-to-server, then sure - that gets done quite a lot (sending a POST with a raw body that is binary such as protobuf). It isn't really a "form" POST though.

If you mean from a browser to the server, no. At minmum that would require a more complete JavaScript protobuf implementation than currently exists (AFAIK).

Comment: Its from browser to server. Did anyone experiment with Google Closure Javascript library, package goog.proto2 to send form data to server.